# sql query with like and or combination

Tags: sql, codeigniter, where-clause, combinations

I need to do something like this sql query but in codeigniter:

```
SELECT `table`.* FROM (`table`) WHERE `name` LIKE '%9%' OR `id` LIKE '%9%' AND (`name` LIKE '%f%' OR `id` LIKE '%f%')
```

I tried to do whit this code:

```
$this->db->select('table.*');
$this->db->from('table');
foreach($data as $d){
    $this->db->like("name", $d)
    $this->db->or_like("id", $d);
}
```

But the result in sql was:

```
SELECT `table`.* FROM (`table`) WHERE `name` LIKE '%9%' OR `id` LIKE '%9%' AND `name` LIKE '%f%' OR `id` LIKE '%f%'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no parenthesis in CI v2. You'll need to use your where() function like:

```
 ->where('mysql in here', null, true);
```

The null is just a placeholder in this case; the TRUE keeps from adding ` (backticks) whihc are usually just in the way here. You can see more in the Users Guide

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tablename');
$this->db->like('name','9','both');
$this->db->or_like('id','9','both');
$this->db->like('name','f','both');
$this->db->or_like('id','f','both');
```